# Find partial match of hash against array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumerable

I have an array of hashes that I am matching against.

```
me = [{paid: true, setup: true, send_to: "somewhere"},
     {paid: true, setup: false, send_to: "somewhere else"},
     {paid: false, setup: true, send_to: "somewhere new"},
     {paid: false, setup: false, send_to: "somewhere outside"}]
```

And I have a hash with only 2 key/value pairs:

```
went = {paid: true, setup: false}
```

What I want to do is compare `went` against `me` and if there is a match return the value in `send_to`

Almost like `include?` but that doesn't work because my `went` hash only has 2 key/value pairs..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything like this?

```
me.find { |item| item[:paid] == went[:paid] && item[:setup] == went[:setup] }&.fetch(:send_to)
```

or this

```
me.find { |item| item.values_at(:paid, :setup) == went.values_at(:paid, :setup) }&.fetch(:send_to)
```

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Ways without hardcoding the keys:

```
me.find { |item| went <= item }&.fetch(:send_to)

me.find { |item| item >= went }&.fetch(:send_to)

me.find(&went.method(:<=))&.fetch(:send_to)

me.find { |item| item.values_at(*went.keys) == went.values }&.fetch(:send_to)

me.find { |item| went.to_a & item.to_a == went.to_a }&.fetch(:send_to)

me.find { |item| item.merge(went) == item }&.fetch(:send_to)
```

I like the first two best. The last one is from [this page](http://olivierlacan.com/posts/proposal-for-a-better-ruby-hash-include/) which shows some history of the subset/superset operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
me.find { |h| h == h.merge(went) }&.[](:send_to)
  #=> "somewhere else"
me.find { |h| h == h.merge({:paid=>true, :setup=>"cat"}) }&.[](:send_to)
  #=> nil
```

Comment: You forgot the second part. And argh, now I'm considering switching back to "h"... I switched from that to "item" for comparability with the other answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I fixed it.